# CellsToTeX copy pasting back into notebook for sub and superscript box for partial derivatives, powers, subscripts etc

Tags: front-end, pdf-format, latex, copy-as

I'm using the CellsToTeX` package, along with the mmacells LaTeX package.

I'm including code with a partial derivative in my pdf.  So for instance to get this

```
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(x\)]\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(2\)]\)
```

in a pdf, I evaluate

```
CopyToClipboard@CellToTeX@Cell[BoxData@MakeBoxes@
  \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(x\)]\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(2\)]\)
,"Input"]
```

which yields the LaTeX

```
\begin{mmaCell}{Input}
  \mmaSub{\(\pmb{\partial}\)}{x}\mmaSup{x}{2}
\end{mmaCell}
```

Most Mathematica code expressions in a LaTeX generated pdf copy and paste great back into a notebook.  When I copy the pdf text

[image: in 2 pd x^2]

and paste back into a notebook, I get `\[PartialD]xx2` with no box structure at all.

## Question

What is a method to make the pretty pdf characters copy/paste back into a notebook?  Perhaps some way to include the string "!(*SubscriptBox[...)" in the pdf.  I suppose if there's no great answers, I'll go to the github repo for the LaTeX package to see if I can hack in more copy/pasting richness.

Comment: Most PDF reader copy texts only, thus the structures have been missing.

Comment: Yes, I'm thinking that the character ∂ or some others can have their copy/paste values customized to emulate box selection.